# assign an address to the Node* in link list?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, structure

```
   this is the structure of my node
    typedef struct Node{
    int x;
    Node* Next;
  };

  // in main() i can make the head pointer,and assign it to NULL i-e 

     Node* start_pointer=NULL;  //this line is in my main() function
                            // and i consider it head pointer


   void add_node(Node* start_pointer){

Node first;
cout<<"Enter the value of X\n ";
cin>>first.x;
if (start_pointer==NULL){
    start_pointer=&first;   //try to assign an address of object of its pointer
    first.Next=NULL;
    }


else {                             

    Node* temp=start_pointer;
    while (temp->Next != NULL){         //program is break at this stage  
        temp=temp->Next;}

    temp->Next=first.Next;                
    first.Next=NULL;

}
```

I am assigning an address to the node* and try to catch it with '->' operator  it is ok ?
every time when i run add_node function it execute but unfortunately it do not go into else condition

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things wrong with your code

Firstly you must allocate new nodes in add_node, not take the address of a local variable.

Instead of this

```
start_pointer=&first;
first.Next=NULL;
```

you should have this

```
start_pointer=new Node;
start_pointer->Next=NULL;
```

Taking the address of `first` is wrong because `first` gets destroyed when you exit the function. So start_pointer will be pointing at an object that has been destroyed and your program will crash. But objects allocated with `new` live until you `delete` them.

Second error is that your function changes `start_pointer` in the `add_node` function. It does not change `start_pointer` in the `main` function. These two variables might have the same name but they are completely different variables. This is why your code never enters the else part of `add_node`. To change start_pointer in main you need to change the `add_node` function to use a reference by adding `&` after the type.

```
void add_node(Node*& start_pointer){ // use a reference
```

Now start_pointer in add_node is a *reference* to start_pointer in main and so changes to start_pointer in add_node will affect start_pointer in main.

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
void add_node (Node* start_pointer) {

    Node first;
    ...
    start_pointer = &first;
    first.Next=NULL;
}
```

stores an address of local variable (object with automatic storage duration), which exists only during the execution of this function. When the execution goes out of scope, `first` is destructed and your pointer becomes invalid ~> if you try to access this pointer, it will yield ***undefined behavior***.

Possible solution might be allocate the `Node` dynamically:

```
start_pointer = new Node();
start_pointer->Next = NULL;
```

just don't forget to free this memory by calling `delete` at some point.